# Stack Overflow is not returning correct search results

Tags: support, search

I just found some odd behavior when searching for the word "binance" on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=binance

The results have nothing to do with the word "binance". If you check the answers, none of them have the word "binance" in their text.

Instead it seems like the search is returning anything that matches the word "bin".

Is this normal?

Obviously I could use quotes to search for the exact word, but that's not the question.

It's just odd how the search works since following that logic one would expect that searching for the word "websockets" would return all the posts with the word "web" in them which is not the case.

Comment: Then actually search ["python-binance"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22python-binance%22) for that, @AlexB . In truth, if you want to search for a specific keyword in questions, then put it in quotes, or (likely better) use a search engine with `site:stackoverflow.com` in the search string.

Comment: @Larnu sure but then i’m only going to get “python-binance” results and will be missing out on other results which contain the word “binance” and don’t relate directly to the “python-binance”. I just think the search is using an odd logic. Following that logic if you were yo search for the word “websockets” then all the posts with the word “web” should appear which would have nothing to do with “websockets”. I’m guessing the word “binance” has been blocked from the search for some reason.

Comment: If you want questions on python-binance then surely searching "python-binance" makes more sense than searching binance...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is lemmatization gone wrong. I know they're using ElasticSearch, which I believe in turn uses Lucene, maybe even the exact algorithm in [PorterStemmer.java](https://github.com/apache/lucene/blob/0b1d8ccba6cf394f707a09217813a25ec1504e50/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/tartarus/snowball/ext/PorterStemmer.java). From experimenting with SO search, it looks like it's removing suffixes (-ance in this case) from non-words (because I tested a few [real words](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/words-that-end-in-ance) and they were not changed). This is why *bin* is highlighted in the results. As another example, searching for *[conance](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=conance)* returns results for "cone".

I'm not sure what benefits this exactly has in practice, or if it can easily be changed system wide. (Other parts of the algorithm are usually helpful, such as removing plural "-s".)

You can disable lemmatization of specific words in your searches by **using quotes**: ["binance"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Binance%22).

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly the answer I was looking for. This makes sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not sure what causes the issue (I could replicate the issue you have mentioned), you may work around the issue by searching for the exact phrase (putting the search term in quotes, like ["binance"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22binance%22))

Comment: yes of course I can do that but that's not really the question. It's just odd how the search works since following that logic one expect that searching for the word "websockets" would return all the posts with the word "web" in them which is not the case.